# Show $\mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \min\{\mu(A\cap B),\mu(A\cap C),\mu(B\cap C)\}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

**Problem:**

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a probability space. Let $A,B,C \in \mathscr{A}$ be sets which fulfills
$$\mu(A\cap B)\geq \frac{3}{5}, \mu(A\cap C)\geq \frac{3}{5}, \mu(B\cap C)\geq \frac{3}{5}$$
Show that
$$\frac{2}{5}\leq \mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \min\left\{\mu(A\cap B),\mu(A\cap C),\mu(B\cap C)\right\}.$$

---

**Attempt:**
I have shown
$$\frac{2}{5}\leq \mu(A\cap B \cap C).$$

But i'm having a real hard time starting on the other inequality.

Any hints?

Comment: If $U\subset V$ then $\mu(U)\le\mu(V)$.

Comment: Pretty sure i got it.

Comment: How did you prove the inequality on LHS?

Comment: @orangeskid one way is to look at $\mu(A\cap B)+ \mu(A\cap C)+ \mu(B\cap C)$ and say it must be less than or equal to some suitable function of $\mu(A\cap B \cap C)$

Comment: @Henry: Thank you! I just found a connected question with a complete proof! Seems not easier than RHS inequality though.

Answer (score 1):

$A < \min\{B,C\}$ is equivalent to saying $A < B$ and $A < C$

Use **monotonicity of measure** to say

1. $\mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \mu(A\cap B)$
2. $\mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \mu(A\cap C)$
3. $\mu(A\cap B \cap C)\leq \mu(B\cap C)$